# Get all lists by ContentType on a SPListCollection

Tags: list

I have a SPListCollection and want to get all lists by a specified ContentType.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Extension Class

```
public class Extensions {
   public static List<SPList> GetLists(this SPListCollection listCollection, string contentTypeName)
        {
            List<SPList> documentLists =
                (from SPList document in listCollection
                 where document.ContentTypes.Cast<SPContentType>()
                     .Any(contentType => string.Compare(contentType.Name, contentTypeName, true) == 0)
                 select document).ToList();

            return documentLists;
        }
}
```

Then you can use the method on any SPListCollection like this:

```
List<SPList> listsByContentType = spListCollection.GetLists("ContentTypeName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out an alternative syntax which should render the same solution:

```
return listCollection.OfType<SPList>()
    .Where(list => list.ContentTypes.OfType<SPContentType>()
        .Any(ct => string.Equals(ct.Name, contentTypeName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it does work.